# Automatically make other li at bottom when removed bottom li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and trying some work.
I am trying to stack li from bottom to top and succeeded. But now the problem is that when i am removing bottom li at runtime the other li's is fixed at their own position. Whereas what i want is to shift other li's to the bottom automatically.    [Click for Jsfiddle Link of my work](https://jsfiddle.net/amz7hbj6/)

```
<div class="lt" align="left">
  <ul class="list-style-none">
    <li><a href="">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="">E</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Can Anyone please help.. I would really appreciate it.. thanks

Comment: May be incomplete jsfiddle. Your li is not dynamicaly removed.

Comment: the question is poorly written and i don't have any idea what you need to do, and how did you try to solve it - so we can't really help.

Comment: Actually i am trying to remove it through chrome inspector DOM elements in normal HTML and CSS file.

Comment: @tarkil, bro as i said i am new to this things. Can you please tell which part is not clear. What i want is if i removed bottom li then all other top li's will shift to the place from where the bottom li is removed..

Comment: OK so basically what you currently have is "normal" HTML so the content is drawn by the browser top-to-bottom. i will try to think of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript to do that...flexbox can do that natively.

```css
.lt {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.list-style-none {
  list-style: none;
}
.list-style-none li {} #switch:checked ~ .lt > ul > li:last-child {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
<label for="switch">Click This</label>

<div class="lt">
  <ul class="list-style-none">
    <li><a href="">A</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">B</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">C</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">D</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">E</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo here.

```
<div class="lt" align="left">
  <ul class="list-style-none">
    <li><a href="">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="">E</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qmt5o1so/

I don't know how you trigger removing the last li, so i use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) here.

If you don't know what it is,you can ignore it,it is just a method to detect the change of DOM.

PS: I don't why there is a few pixels of deviation in the demo.